# Sitecore 9.3.0 XP Scaled instance on Developer Machine

Tags: scaling

I installed scaled architecture in my developer machine. I see 12 processes in IIS

1. XP1.sitecore.CM,
2. XP1.sitecore.identityserver
3. XP1.sitecore.CD
4. XP1.sitecore.collection
5. XP1.sitecore.ma
6. XP1.sitecore.reporting
7. XP1.sitecore.processingEngine
8. XP1.sitecore.refdata
9. XP1.sitecore.reporting
10. XP1.sitecore.search
11. XP1.sitecore.rep
12. XP1.sitecore.prc

Each process has own configurations and connection string. I would like to know how to setup in Higher environment. Do we really need to use dedicated server for each role in higher environment( DEV, QE) ?

Could anyone please suggest the recommended approach and how to segregate the above roles in higher environment. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

There is no one good way of setting up roles for environments. It all depends on your project specific requirements and load.

Sample configuration which is an example of Sitecore 10 setup goes like that:

- Identity Server
- CM + xDB Reporting
- CD
- xDB Processing
- Cortex Reporting Service + Marketing Operations + Marketing Automation reporting + xConnect Collection search
- Cortex Processing service + xxConnect Collection + xConnect Reference data
- (Horizon?)

While it may work well in some cases, in other it may be better to have e.g. separate server for reporting role.

Here is an article describing ARM templates for Sitecore 10 XP, topologies and tiers. While it may not be up to date, it kind of shows it quite well where the load goes and how your resources need to grow depending on the number of visits:

https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0923605